# ipython ipdb, when invoked via ipdb.set_trace(), does not remember the command history while debugging

Tags: python, ipython, ipdb

iPython does remember the command history if I run `ipython` normally, e.g. to mess around testing basic things in the repl, but I would like to be able to pull up the debugging commands from the previous debug session, and I am doing my debugging by simply running my program as normal, where the program contains

```
import ipdb
def info(type, value, info):
    import traceback
    traceback.print_exception(type, value, info)
    ipdb.pm()

import sys
sys.excepthook = info
trace = ipdb.set_trace
```

Which is to set it up so I can write `trace()` anywhere in my program to start debugging there when I run the program, or for it to automatically start postmortem debugging when it dies on its own.

Python with iPython has been leaps and bounds beyond other languages when it comes to quick code/test iterations and I'm just so close to nirvana at this point...

Comment: I think i saw somewhere something about SQLite. Maybe once I install that it will start to work?

Comment: Looks like you've hit [this bug](https://github.com/ipython/ipython/issues/682) or a related one within ipython.

Comment: Damn. 3 months and I can't even remember if this problem has been solved or not, I have not been messing about with my one python script that makes use of this. I feel like ipython will simply not remember *anything* if SQLite isn't configured, which would indicate this is a bug if it did remember stuff some of the time. I'll have to investigate this further later; my kickstart script is already set to `pip install` ipython and sqlite (and readline) automatically. @pwaller thanks for linking that, breadcrumbs are good to have

Comment: @StevenLu Do you have a way around this?

Comment: @Phani No I have not looked into this anymore. `pudb` looks interesting and I might switch to that, if i ever go back to Python again :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [History across ipdb sessions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26810905/history-across-ipdb-sessions)

Comment: Any updates one this? Has anyone submitted PR for this improvement?

Answer (score 3):

I use [pudb](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pudb) instead. It enables getting to a real ipython shell from the debugger and all the commands there are saved