# History across ipdb sessions

Tags: python, ipython, ipdb

This question has been [asked](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17138106/1224076) before, but I couldn't find a good answer. So, I am trying to ask again.

I would like my ipdb to remember commands across sessions. Right now, it can pull up commands executed in Ipython sessions but not from old ipdb sessions. It would be a huge time saver, if I could have this feature.

Does anyone have a solution to this problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had your same problem, so I [forked](https://github.com/michelesr/ipdb) the project and add a patch for persistent history. You can install the forked version of ipdb with pip:

```
pip install git+https://github.com/michelesr/ipdb.git
```

Just make sure that your IPython version is 5.0 or higher. Implementation info can be found in this [article](https://michelesr.github.io/2016/11/22/ipdb-history.html).

Comment: I get that forking desire often with `ipdb`.

Answer (score 1):

If you are wiling to use another debugger, [trepan](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/trepan) has does save history across sessions.

Answer (score 1):

- Create a file with the following content
- Import that file with `execfile(...)` in your `~/.pdbrc` file

```
def use_file_history():
    import os
    from IPython.terminal.debugger import TerminalPdb
    from prompt_toolkit.history import FileHistory
    cmdloop = TerminalPdb.cmdloop
    def cmdloop_prime(self, intro=None):
        fname = os.path.join(os.path.expanduser('~'), '.ipdb_history')
        self._pt_app.buffer.history = FileHistory(fname)
        self._pt_app.buffer.reset()
        cmdloop(self, intro)
    TerminalPdb.cmdloop = cmdloop_prime

use_file_history()
del use_file_history
```

---

PS—you can find this code, and more patches, in [this gist with ipdb patches](https://gist.github.com/akuhn/195b4ec4305e809af2074b07d4628b14)

Comment: I get `*** NameError: name 'execfile' is not defined` when I try and do this.  Is `execfile` pdb only, not ipdb?  Am I missing something else?  Can you post a minimal `~/.pdbrc` example please? (ipdb==0.13.13, ipython==7.31.1)